# Jade-lang add manifest file

Tags: node.js, pug, manifest.cache

I would like to know how to add the manifest file to node.js site with jade-lang and express. I found this as an [issue 239](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/239) in github. My question is how can I add some data into the buffer without while we wait for the resolution of the issue.

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to need this in one of my projects soon, so I was curious to give it a try. There is effectively a problem if you try to do it in a single file:

```
!!! 5
if useManifest
    html(lang="en", manifest="cache.manifest")
else
    html(lang="en")

    head
        title sample title
    body
        p some content...
```

This renders a messed up HTML. However, the following seems to work just fine (it's definitely a workaround):

In `routes\index.js` :

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('testJade', { layout: false, useManifest: true })
};
```

In `views\testJadeInclude.jade`:

```
!!!5
if useManifest
    html(lang="en", manifest="cache.manifest")
        block content
else
    html(lang="en")
        block content
```

And finally, in `views\testJade.jade`:

```
include testJadeInclude
    block append content
        head
            title sample title
        body
            p some content
```

Then based on whatever you wish (such as if the client is a mobile browser, or whatever), you set useManifest to true or false.

And I just tested another possibility, which is kind of the other way around. Instead of including the doctype and html tag in your content file (via a block append), you include the content file in the doctype-html file, so it looks like this:

```
!!! 5
if useManifest
    html(lang="en", manifest="cache.manifest")
        include contentFile
else
    html(lang="en")
        include contentFile
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way to do this in jade:
Just try this

```
html(manifest=_condition_ ? "cache.manifest" : undefined)
```

This code checks if *condition* is true. If it is, manifest is set to "cache.manifest". Otherwise it'll be set to `undefined` and dropped.